# jQuery objects don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

When I store a jQuery object in a variable, like this:

```
var $myObject = $("div#comments");
```

...I can't use the object $myObject!

This is what I'm doing to change the html of div#comments:

```
$myObject.html(data);
```

It does nothing. I already tried this way too, this time to select an element inside div#comments:

```
$("div.comment", $myObject);
```

It doesn't work.

I just want to be able to save an element in a variable and then **use it**!

*Note: some people don't put $ before the variable name, like this: myObject.*

Comment: You are doing something else wrong; that should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you calling it *after* the document is loaded?

```
     // This will ensure that the code doesn't run until
     //    the document has loaded
$(function() {
    var $myObject = $("div#comments");
});
```

*(This is a shortcut for jQuery's `.ready()` method.)*

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/

As long as the document is loaded, and you have a `<div>` with the ID `comments` on the page when it loads, it should work.

Also remember that there can only be *one* element on the page with any given ID. Because of this, it is actually a little better (quicker) to do `$("#comments");` instead of `$("div#comments");`.

Comment: @Akay - Well, yes and no. This is a shortcut for the same thing. :o)

Comment: Oh I see, and can some one please tell me how to make my code look like code :D in the comments.. the above comment is embarasing

Comment: @Akay - Use the `grave accent` character, which is above the left tab key. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent = `

Answer (score 1):

You've only provided snippits of your code, so it is impossible to tell for sure, but the odds are that you are running the code in a `<script>` element that appears before the `<div>` element and don't do anything (such as use the ready event) to delay the execution of the code until the div exists.

The result is that you get a jQuery object which found no elements. Move the script element so it is after the div. [Just before the end tag for the body](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) is a good place.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is perfectly valid and should work. Are you dynamically appending the comments div? You should `alert( $myObject.length )` to see if it's 0 or 1, if its 0 that means it's never picked up.

You may need to bind the `var` statement until after dom ready, window load, or your ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that syntax is perfectly fine so something else is going on. Can you show your markup? And what do you get if you add an alert($myObject.length)? And one last thing to check... are you running this inside an on-ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everyone for that.
I got the solution.

I thought about the order the things were loaded in the DOM and found the solution.
The problem (with the markup) was:

```
<div id="comments">    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    loadComments(params);
    </script>
</div>
```

The code above was written by PHP!
So it executed the function as soon as the browser read the code.
I already tried to put the script on the end of the page, **after the function was called**. The funcion was not defined yet.

So, the funcion loadComments should be executed after the div was ready AND after the function was defined.

I wrapped the code between the  tags with a .ready(), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    loadComments(params);
});
</script>
```

It was a distraction.
Sorry everyone!
Thanks a lot.

If you have the same problem and you didn't understand what I did, ask me. XD